# Not able to write into a file using NASM programming

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am using file handling program to write into a file named "a.txt" in Ubuntu which is present in the same directory as that of my "asm" file.
But, nothing is getting written into that file after I've executed my program.
here, is the code:

```
%macro print 2     ;print on monitor
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    syscall     
%endmacro
%macro accept 2    ;accept from user
    mov rax,0
    mov rdi,0
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    syscall
%endmacro
%macro exit 0
    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
%endmacro
%macro fopen 1
    mov rax,2
    mov rdi,%1  ;name of file
    mov rsi,2
    mov rdx,0777o
    syscall
%endmacro
%macro fread 3
    mov rax,0
    mov rdi,%1
    mov rsi,%2
    mov rdx,%3
    syscall
%endmacro
%macro fwrite 3 
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,%1
    mov rsi,%2
    mov rdx,%3 
    syscall 
%endmacro
%macro fclose 1
    mov rax,3
    mov rdi,%1
    syscall
%endmacro
section .data

    msg db 10,"Enter file_name to open : "
    len equ $-msg


    msg4 db 10 ,"written into file "
    len4 equ $-msg4

    msg5 db 10 ,"Not written success "
    len5 equ $-msg5

section .bss
    fname1 resb 17  ;1 for enter
    fdesc resb 8            
    buff resb 103
    bufflen resb 8

section .code
global _start
_start:
    print msg,len

    accept fname1,20
    dec rax
    mov byte[fname1+rax],0

    fopen fname1

    mov [fdesc],rax

    fread [fdesc],buff,100
    dec rax
    mov [bufflen],rax
    print buff,[bufflen]

    fwrite [fdesc],msg4,len4
    cmp rax,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEH
    je haha
    print msg4,len4
    exit
    haha:
        print msg5,len5
    fclose fname1   
exit
```

Is there any way to know whether content has been successfully been written into the text file in assembly.

Comment: Check the return value the same [way you would for `write`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write)? (except you would probably get `-EWHATEVER` directly in `rax` rather than in `errno`)

Comment: I did that but rax is not returning -1 in my case which means that characters are getting written into it !!

Comment: Your `fdesc` is only two bytes instead of 8. PS: also your `print buff,bufflen` is wrong but that's unrelated to writing in the file.

Comment: Yeah, I updated it.But can't still fix the problem !!

Comment: It works here with that fix.

Comment: Yes. It is working. Thanks for pointing it out !!